# Attaching new file causes the page to refresh

Tags: bulkification

Even when I use the `reRender` attribute, the page is refreshing. How can I prevent that?

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="bulkattach">
   <apex:form id="form1">
    <apex:pageBlock >
          <apex:pageBlockSection >
              <apex:inputField value="{!par.name}" />
          </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock >
          <apex:repeat var="p" value="{!listparent}" >
              <apex:inputFile value="{!p.body}" fileName="{!p.name}" title=""/>
          </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlock> 
          <apex:commandButton value="addAtch" action="{!addatch}"  />
          <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!save}" />
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class bulkattach {

public list<attachment> listparent { get; set; }

public parent__c par { get; set; }

public bulkattach(){

   listparent=new list<attachment>();

   par=new parent__c();

   attachment  doc=new attachment();

   listparent.add(doc);

}

public PageReference addatch() {

    System.debug(listparent);

    attachment atc=new attachment();

    listparent.add(atc);

    return null;
}

public PageReference save() { 

    insert par;
    system.debug(listparent); 
    for(attachment d: listparent){

      d.parentid=par.id;

     }
      insert listparent;  
    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: Please use html button and use onclick instead of apex:commndButton. It will solve your issue. commandButton refresh the page. We should use only for save and redirection purpose.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to start by looking into the `apex:action*` VisualForce components (`apex:actionFunction`, `apex:actionRegion`, `apex:actionSupport`, etc). Guessing at what you're trying to accomplish here, you'll probably want an `apex:actionFunction` for your **addatch**, which you'll call from your **addatch** button's **OnClick** event (JavaScript).

Answer (score 2):

Please use an html button with `onclick` event, instead of `apex:commndButton`. It will solve your issue. `apex:commandButton` refreshes the page by default. We should use `apex:commandButton` only for save and redirection purpose.

Reason why it was refreshing your page. bcz commnadButton generate "submit" type button which refresh the page. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandButton.htm